# Running a java application on a remote server

Tags: java, jsp

I want to run a standalone java application on a remote server.  It would not be accessible to clients, but would do background calculations and interact with a database and Secure Socket connection to a third party site.  It would also interact with a php site.

Do I have to deploy this with JSP, or can I write a standalone application?  If so, how would I deploy a standalone java application (jar file) on a remote server?  I understand that I must have them install a jvm on the server (not a problem) but then how would I deploy it (if possible).  Would I start it with a command line?

I know I have much to learn, but I am not sure how I would access the command line on a remote server.  Through the cPanel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to set up some firewall rules to allow access to that server.  I'm hoping that you don't expose that server naked to the Internet.

If all you need is database access exposed on the Internet, I don't see why it can't be a secured web app deployed on a servlet/JSP engine and accessed via a web server.  You can leverage basic auth for security, JDBC access to the database from the server, and servlets as controllers to accept requests in a nice REST API.

It'll save you the complications of sockets and inventing your own protocol (use HTTP), starting and stopping the application (now it's just a web server/servlet engine), and deployment (send a WAR file).

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, the socket is required for the third party access, and the php site is fully written.  Thus the http access.  Is is possible to deploy a .jar from a server?

Comment: Your 3rd parties can't make HTTP requests?  Where is the PHP site?  Can't a servlet make a GET/POST request to a it?

Answer (score 0):

Does it really must be a 'standalone' application? I think that in your case the best match would be to use Spring container to load your application within some server (tomcat?) and expose services via standard controllers - with Spring you only have to add some annotations on services methods actually.

Then, your php site can interact with these controllers using for example ajax requests.

If your application is written already, you can easily transform it to run within Spring container. It's very non-invasive and promotes usage of POJOs.